# How to create a audit table in azure data factory which will hold the status for the pipeline run in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, etl, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement where a Azure Data Pipeline is running and inside that we have a data flow where different tables are loaded from ADLS to Azure Sql Database. So the issue is I wanted to store the status of the pipeline like success or failure in an audit table as well as Primary Key column ID which is present in Azure SQL database table  so that when I want to filter  job I on the primary key like for which ID job is success I should get from the audit table.i managed to did something in stored procedure and store the status in a table but I am unable to add a column like ID .Below is the screen shot of pipeline.

The Report_id column is from the table which is loaded from Dataload pipeline.How to add that in audit table so the every time when a pipline runs Report_id is captured and stored in audit table

Audit Table where I want to add Report id

[image]

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Data Flow must have a sink.  So, after the Data Flow completes, you need to use a Lookup activity to get the value of that Report_Id from the sink.  Then, you can set that to a variable and pass that into your Stored Procedure.  (You could also just pass it directly to the Stored Procedure from the Lookup using the same expression you would use to set the variable.)

[image]

Comment: I am able to pass the Report Id but the problem is coming in stored procedure success failure tab,I want that if load is success then lookup should trigger and load success status and if load is failure it should load failure,but currently everything is becoming success because it is dependent on look up tab.

Comment: Check the Data Flow output to see if there is a success/failure flag that you could use for setting that value.  (Sorry, I don't have a Data Flow set up to test for you at the moment.) 
 If the output contains nothing usable, just add a duplicate Lookup task along the Failure pathway.  That's not the cleanest solution since it basically duplicates the logging activities, but it will work for you if you aren't able to simplify it as per the first suggestion.